# Multi domain SSL for a single business website

Tags: ssl

I am working with a client who would have website as .com, .in, .com.au, .jp, .eu etc. We are planning to buy an SSL. Its a eCommerce site and needs to be secured. What SSL certificate should i choose to support various domains together?
Should i buy a SAN certificate? I would need some directions here. What will show up when some one clicks on the certificate of .jp webiste.

Comment: You can't buy an "SSL" which is a protocol. What you buy is an X.509 certificate. And your question is off-topic on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. You will need a unified communications (UC, SAN) certificate. Each TLD being different causes the domain to be different.

A UC certificate will let you bond all of the domains under one trust relationship. However, I would recommend just having different SSL certificates for each of them unless you plan on running them all on the same host machine.

Another potentially viable alternative, depending on how many other certificates you will need, would be to apply for a certificate authority (CA) trust with say VeriSign or any other CA. This would let you control your own enterprise PKI and issue any number of certificates while only paying one very large fee up front.

Comment: What if in the case of one of the domains is just redirected to a main domain (for example redirection of .net to .com) in the same host machine? Is still needed an UC/SAN certificate?

Comment: @Dez That is correct, or you could just use different certificates. It depends on your organizational needs.